# Node js filespec as command line argument

Tags: node.js, file, arguments

When I pass a file spec such as *.txt as an argument to node it fills out argv with all the matches. (I'm on OSX Yosemite - so sort of linux). This is fine but I would like to either not have this expanded so I can use vinyl-fs to locate the files, or be able to specify a wild carded search that will parse sub folders.

P.S. I know I can get away with '*.txt' or ./*.txt as parameters just not *.txt.

Maybe I should just call it a documentation issue ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, OSX is linux, and I assume you are in the default bash shell.  So the shell expands *.txt before passing it to node.  To change this behavior simply wrap the command argument with single quotes, e.g., '*.txt'.

Comment: You're right Darryl, I re-worked my argument processing to cope with the auto expansion. Ended up with a better solution that accepted multiple file specs.